# Find my server ip address with Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

How can I find my server ip address asynchronously with Twisted ?

I am running an ubuntu and a centos and the results are always the same, the ip returned from the methods exposed belows are always: `127.0.1.1` instead of my real private ip address.

EDIT: this isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25850698/379105) as proposed, my last try is inspired from this answer, what I want is a way to achieve this in asynchrounous way.

**Trying to retrieve the ip with a tcp server**

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, endpoints, reactor


class FindIpClient(protocol.Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        print self.transport.getPeer()  # prints 127.0.1.1
        self.transport.loseConnection()


def main():
    f = protocol.ClientFactory()
    f.protocol = FindIpClient
    ep = endpoints.clientFromString(reactor, 'tcp:127.0.0.1:1234')
    ep.connect(f)
    reactor.run()

main()
```

**Using reactor.resolve**

```
import socket

from twisted.internet import reactor


def gotIP(ip):
    print(ip)  # prints 127.0.1.1
    reactor.stop()


reactor.resolve(socket.getfqdn()).addCallback(gotIP)
reactor.run()
```

**This works, but I am not sure about its *asynchronous-ity***

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 0))
s.setblocking(False)
local_ip_address = s.getsockname()[0]
print(local_ip_address)  # prints 10.0.2.40
```

How can I get my private ip address asynchrounously ?

Here is my `/etc/hosts` if it can help:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
127.0.1.1 mymachine mymachine
```

*I don't know why I have `127.0.1.1 mymachine mymachine` in my hosts btw :/*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Comment: I'm assuming `127.0.1.1` is a typo?

Comment: no it isn't, I get 127.0.1.1

Comment: What exactly is your "real private address"? How do you define that?

Comment: Hmm, then your `/etc/hosts` file must have that as your loopback address.

Comment: I mean the ip address bound on my eth0, in my case something like 10.0.2.40

Comment: Why do you need an asynchronous method? There is no long-running operation, you are just making a server-side socket object and grabbing some metadata about it.

Comment: I am beginning with twisted, I want to be sure that I don't run any *possibly long* operations. I'd also like to kow why on Linuxes the `socket.getfqdn()` resolve doesn't work

Comment: How about inspecting something like `ifconfig` and look for `eth0` then? I'd be surprised if there wasn't a Python wrapper for this even.

Comment: I don't know that `local_ip_address = s.getsockname()[0]` could be any more "possibly long" than anything else.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I've ended up keeping this solution as it **cannot be long** :

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 0))
s.setblocking(False)
local_ip_address = s.getsockname()[0]
print(local_ip_address)  # prints 10.0.2.40
```

Comment: it's a `twisted` question and you answer `sockets`?

Answer (score 0):

From [Python Twisted: restricting access by IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273297/python-twisted-restricting-access-by-ip-address)

> d = self.transport.getHost () ; print d.type, d.host, d.port

Doesn't work for some protocols like receiving on a broadcast UDP